# Esperar a que una pantalla de carga no exista java

Tags: java, selenium

Hola buenas tardes amigos

Tengo una duda en selenium con java

Como puedo hacer para esperar a que una pantalla de carga ya no exista y si sigue existiendo seguir esperando.

Espero me puedan orientar un poco, gracias

```
   public void waitForElementPresent(String element) throws Exception
{
    functions.waitForElementPresent(element);
}
```

Aquí espero a que el elemento exista pero desaparece después de un tiempo que no es siempre el mismo, como podria decir que si sigue existiendo siga esperando

Esta es la pantalla de carga.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Angel podrias compartir algun codigo que tengas de base

Comment: listo espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Podrías plantearlo asi

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Esperate hasta que el elemento no exista 60 segundos maximo